# Android - OutOfMemoryError reading 2D codes with camera

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

Context:
I have developed an app with Xamarin.Android that reads 2D codes -datamatrix- (among other things).
For reading 2D codes I have used a third party library (NeoReader)
The app must read datamatrix thoroughly, (e.g. 400 straight).

The behavior is the following:

1. Activity A starts the reading by calling Activity B (the one with the camera)
2. Once Activity B decodes a datamatrix, returns the value to Activity A
3. Activity A wait a second and starts from point 1)

   - the loop can be interrupted with the back key

I tested the app in a Samsung S4 mini running Android 4.2 and it works fine (at least I don't get the OutOfMemoryError)

Then I tested the App in a Motorola Moto G running Android 5.1 and after decoding between 75 and 80 datamatrix, I get the OutOfMemoryError.

This is the line with the error:
**Java.Lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1843212 byte allocation with 1709964 free bytes and 1669KB until OOM**

Please find attached the file with the full log, in case some charitable soul want to add some light to this problem:
[OutOfMemory.txt](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByZJ0Mvqrdy7dGNLbjltbHFtUUk/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: It might be helpful to use `Allocation Tracker` in Android Device Monitor to see what's happening natively. You can also use the Xamarin profiler to see what's happening on the managed end. These items will help pinpoint what's getting allocated and not released. https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/investigate-ram.html

Comment: Odd thing to suggest, but try calling GC.Collect() before Activity A starts the flow again. Images on Android eat memory and can easily cause OOM errors, but doing an explicit GC.Collect can clean up the memory before it runs out.

Comment: @JimBobBennett I already did that, then the OOM appears when around 90 datamatrix are decoded.
As I'm working in Xamarin and I have built a binding library in order to use a java library, I find it difficult to determine where the leak could be.
I think I'm going to take the appropriate time to try to solve the problem using the monitoring tools. I already tried with Xamarin Profiler (first time I use it) but it wasn't much help for me.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to answer this one myself.
I added more time between readings (changed from 500 to 1500 ms), forced GC before every new read, and moved some references to events in the camera activity.
That's it, the problem seems to be solved.

P.S. I also reproduced the problem in Java, using a sample app, so is not exclusively a Xamarin problem.